# Add a string of html attributes to a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have a string of attributes written in valid html, and I want to put those attributes on an actual html *element* (not a html *string* of an element).

For example, I have the string of attributes in the sensibly named `attributesStr` variable, and I want to add those attributes to the `#htmlElement` div.

```js
var attributesStr = "";
attributesStr += " class='regularClass'"; // Needs to handle key value attributes.
attributesStr += " title='Title... with spaces!'"; // And attributes with spaces.
attributesStr += " style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'"; // And style with multiple properties.
attributesStr += " data-attributenovalue"; // And attributes with no value.

// Your special code to add the attributes to `#htmlElement` goes here.
```

```html
<div id="htmlElement">
    The HTML element!
</div>
```

After the JQuery / JavaScript code is run, `#htmlElement` should look like:

```
<div id="htmlElement" class='regularClass' title='Title... with spaces!' style='color: red; font-weight: bold;' data-attributenovalue>
    The HTML element!
</div>
```

How can I do this in JavaScript or Jquery?

---

First attempt: I was thinking I could do this by `.split()`ing `attributesStr` on spaces, and then splitting each individual attribute key value pair on the `=`, and then iterating that array and adding each key value pair with JQuery's `.prop()` or `.attr()`, but this wouldn't work for two reasons:

1. It would fail on the `style` and `title` attributes because they have spaces.
2. It *might* fail on the attributes with no value.

Comment: `attributesStr.match(/[^\s=]+(=['][^']*['])?/g)` this will get you the first split

Comment: You're making this harder than it needs to be by hacking around the pre-built string. Can you not apply the styles at the point you build that string? Or even create an object with those values to be applied later?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've already found a different solution to my original problem, I was just curious if there was a way to do this in JS/JQuery :)

Comment: @tallberg Please feel free to post an answer if you think you have a solution that works :)

Comment: Sure, there's lots of ways to do anything, but most of them aren't the best way for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the `attributesStr` and insert it into the existing `outerHTML`.  To achieve this, you need to reconstruct the node by removing the existing tag, injecting the string, and putting back the rest of the html.

```js
var attributesStr = "";
attributesStr += " class='regularClass'"; // Needs to handle key value attributes.
attributesStr += " title='Title... with spaces!'"; // And attributes with spaces.
attributesStr += " style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'"; // And style with multiple properties.
attributesStr += " data-attributenovalue"; // And attributes with no value.

var element = document.getElementById('htmlElement');

var tag = element.tagName;

element.outerHTML = '<' + tag + attributesStr + element.outerHTML.substring(tag.length + 1);
```

```html
<div id="htmlElement">
  The HTML element!
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! That really works, however if you inspect the element you'll find that it adds a new element inside the old `#htmlElement`. Try messing around with `outerHtml` to fix that.

Comment: yeah, silly jQuery's `html()`.  might as well not use it at all

Answer (score 2):

You can use **.attr()** to do this in jquery. Here is the working snippet.

[click here for attr() usage](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#htmlElement").attr("class", "regularClass");
$("#htmlElement").attr("title", "Title... with spaces!");
$("#htmlElement").attr("style", "color: red; font-weight: bold");
$("#htmlElement").attr("data-attributenovalue",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="htmlElement">
    The HTML element!
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use a string with all the attributes, I absolutely can't modify the source format of that string. I included that `attributesStr` variable as an example of what the string looks like.

Comment: You want to use the string with all attributes instead of adding it separately using attr right?

Comment: Yup, works perfectly :) Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dummHTML = $("<div "+attributesStr+"></div>");   
$.each(dummHTML[0].attributes, function(i,v){
 $('#htmlElement').attr(v.nodeName,v.nodeValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best option but if its required to use the full string:

The idea is: take the content of the element, then remove it and create it again with the new attributes:

```js
var attributesStr = "";
attributesStr += " class='regularClass'"; // Needs to handle key value attributes.
attributesStr += " title='Title... with spaces!'"; // And attributes with spaces.
attributesStr += " style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'"; // And style with multiple properties.
attributesStr += " data-attributenovalue"; // And attributes with no value.

// Your special code to add the attributes to `#htmlElement` goes here.
var $innerHTML = $("#htmlElement").html()
$("#htmlElement").remove()
var $newElement = "<div id='htmlElement' " + attributesStr + ">" + $innerHTML + "</div>" 

$("body").after($newElement)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="htmlElement">
    The HTML element!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not separating your string with ','

```js
var attributesStr = "";
attributesStr = attributesStr + " class='regularClass'," ; // Needs to handle key value attributes.
attributesStr = attributesStr +" title='Title... with spaces!',"; // And attributes with spaces.
attributesStr = attributesStr +" style='color: red; font-weight: bold;',"; // And style with multiple properties.
attributesStr = attributesStr +" data-attributenovalue,"; // And attributes with no value.

var array = attributesStr.split(',');

array.forEach(function(item){
 property = item.split('=');
 $('#htmlElement').attr(property[0].trim());
 if(property[1]) $('#htmlElement').attr(property[0].trim(), property[1].trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="htmlElement">
    The HTML element!
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use a string with all the attributes, I absolutely can't modify the source format of that string. I included that `attributesStr` variable as an example of what the string looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the first split

```
attributesStr.match(/[^\s=]+(=['][^']*['])?/g)
```

result:

```
["class='regularClass'", "title='Title... with spaces!'", "style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'", "data-attributenovalue"]
```

Then in an `foreach` you can handle the attrs as you suggested.

Comment: Ok, this looks like it might work. Could you include the rest of the code to handle the attrs? Then it would indisputably work.